# I got 'syntax error: "(" unexpected' (expecting "done")

Tags: bash, shell

I have a very simple shell script which I'm using to loop through directories, and call another shell script. I wrote it on my local machine ([OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X) running Bash 3.2) and am using it on a remote server running Bash 4.2.

On the server, when I type `which bash`, I get `/bin/bash`, so I added the line on top. I still get this error, pointing to the line that begins `arrIN=`...

> 8: run_all_verification.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")

The shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Base name for all experiments
BASE_EXP_ID=$1;

for i in ${BASE_EXP_ID}*
do
        # Split file name by "__"
        arrIN=(${i//__/ });
        EXP_ID=${arrIN[0]}
        NUM_FEATURES=${arrIN[1]}
        echo "${EXP_ID} ${NUM_FEATURES}"

        sh run_verification.sh ${EXP_ID} ${NUM_FEATURES}

done
```

Comment: If you mean `bash` then run `bash` and not `sh` (for `run_verification.sh`). How are you running the posted script (which is `run_all_verification.sh` I'm assuming)? `./run_all_verification.sh`? `sh run_all_verification.sh`? `bash run_all_verification.sh`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your error message is from Dash, probably because you ran `sh filename`.

To run a script with Bash, use `bash filename` (or `./filename`).

Comment: I didn't realize there's a difference. On my local machine, and on the server, I run `sh run_all_verification.sh...`

Comment: Just never run a bash script with `sh`. It will almost always fail on Debian-ish distributions where `sh` is `dash`. It can even fail on OS X where `sh` is `bash`, due to compatibility settings.

Comment: When I run `./run_all..sh` I get 'Permission denied'. When I run `bash run_all.sh`, I get 'Cannot open run_verification.sh', which is the script that is being called internally

Comment: Disregard. I had the wrong file name

Comment: You can give yourself permission to execute your file with `chmod +x yourfile`. Remember that `sh run_verification.sh` has the same bash vs sh issue that you originally saw, and that it will look for `run_verification.sh` in the current working directory and not necessarily the directory where `run_all.sh` is.