# Math with nested double-parens, work with bash on CentOS but not Ubuntu

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                              
num=1
(( ((num % 2)) == 0 ))
```

I am able to run this script from a centos machine, but I cannot run it on my ubuntu 16.04.

On the latter, the following occurs:

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Please copy-paste the code instead of posting screenshot

Comment: This post will become worthless when the screenshot expires.

Comment: What is the bash version on your centos?  And on your ubuntu?

Comment: Edited this question to comply with http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- previously it contained far too much code unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: BTW, how are you starting it? Are you sure you're running this with `./yourscript` or `bash yourscript` and not `sh yourscript`?

Comment: ...duplicative of, among others, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287474/syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-done

Answer (score 2):

This syntax error will occur when your code is run with dash (which Ubuntu uses as `/bin/sh`) instead of bash.

```
$ dash -c 'num=1; (( ((num % 2)) == 0 )); echo $?'
dash: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

vs, in bash, proper operation:

```
$ bash -c 'num=1; (( ((num % 2)) == 0 )); echo $?'
1
```

Be sure that you either run your script as `./yourscript` (which will honor the `#!/bin/bash` line), or `bash yourscript` (which uses bash explicitly), and not `sh yourscript` (which is guaranteed to run only a POSIX-compliant shell interpreter, as opposed to one with bash extensions).

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to

```
if (( num % 2 == 0 ))
```

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: This change doesn't actually fix the problem; `if (( ... ))` is just as invalid in POSIX sh, and in bash, the nested double parens would be harmless.